# python question on scope and variables - not sure how this variable is defined and the technique used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across this code snipped on decorators which I am reading about:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0

    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

print(succ.calls)
for i in range(10):
    succ(i)
    
print(succ.calls)
```

I am a little puzzled how the variable

```
succ.calls
```

comes into this. How is it defined, what is the scope of this variable?  To me it looks related to the function

```
succ
```

but it is not defined there, it seems defined in the function

```
helper
```

I tried something similar with:

```
def do_something():
    do_something.my_var = 6
    
print(do_something.my_var)
```

as expected there are attribute errors.
Thanks for any advice.

I am uncertain what this python technique is called so am unable to look it up.

Comment: What you tried last failed because the line `do_something.my_var = 6` was never executed, because you never called `do_something`.

Comment: `succ.calls` is `helper.calls = 0`, because `succ` refers to `return helper`. The decorated function *becomes* what the decorator returns.